# Application Configuration in PHP

Tags: php, dependency-injection, singleton

I'm learning PHP and I know too many ways to configure the application.

I use this method:

Folder:

> - app
>
>   - config
>
>     - app.php
>     - db.php
> - src
>
>   - class.php
> - index.php

File:

```
// app.php
return [
    'environment' => 'development',

    'meta' => [
        'description' => 'Description',

        'title' => 'Title'
    ],

    ..
];

// db.php
return [
    'connection' => 'mysql',

    ..
];
```

And some class for configuration:

```
namespace App;

use Closure;

class Singleton
{

    private static $instance = [];

    public static function get($name)
    {
        $instance = self::$instance[$name];

        if ($instance instanceof Closure) {
            $instance = $instance();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    public static function set($name, $instance)
    {
        if (is_string($instance)) {
            $instance = new $instance();
        }

        self::$instance[$name] = $instance;
    }

    private function __clone() {}

    private function __construct() {}

    private function __wakeup() {}
}

class Config
{

    public static $data = [];

    public static function forget($key)
    {
        Arr::forget(self::$data, $key);
    }

    public static function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        $segment = explode('.', $key);

        if (! array_key_exists($file = current($segment), self::$data)) {
            if (is_readable($path = 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file . '.php')) {
                self::$data[$file] = require_once $path;
            }
        }

        return Arr::get(self::$data, $key, $default);
    }

    public static function set($key, $value)
    {
        Arr::set(self::$data, $key, $value);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $argument)
    {
        $key = $method;
        $default = null;

        if (count($argument)) {
            $key .= '.' . array_shift($argument);
            $default = array_shift($argument);
        }

        return self::get($key, $default);
    }

    public function __call($method, $argument)
    {
        return self::__callStatic($method, $argument);
    }
}

class Arr
{

    public static function forget(&$array, $key)
    {
        $temp = &$array;

        foreach ((array) $key as $path) {
            $segment = explode('.', $path);

            while (count($segment) > 1) {
                $part = array_shift($segment);

                if (self::has($array, $part)) {
                    $array = &$array[$part];
                }
            }

            unset($array[array_shift($segment)]);

            $array = &$temp;
        }
    }

    public static function get($array, $key, $default = null)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $array;
        }

        if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return $array[$key];
        }

        foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
            if (! is_array($array) || ! array_key_exists($segment, $array)) {
                return $default;
            }

            $array = $array[$segment];
        }

        return $array;
    }

    public static function has($array, $key)
    {
        if (empty($array) || is_null($key)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
            return true;
        }

        foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
            if (! is_array($array) || ! array_key_exists($segment, $array)) {
                return false;
            }

            $array = $array[$segment];
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static function set(&$array, $key, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $array = $value;
        }

        $data = explode('.', $key);

        while (count($data) > 1) {
            $key = array_shift($data);

            if (! is_array($array) || ! array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
                $array[$key] = [];
            }

            $array = &$array[$key];
        }

        $array[array_shift($data)] = $value;

        return $array;
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

```
function app($key = null, $default = null) {
    App\Singleton::set('config', 'App\Config');

    return $key ? App\Singleton::get('config')->get('app.' . $key, $default) : App\Singleton::get('config');
}

echo app('environment');
echo app('domain', 'http://domain.com');
echo app('meta.title');
echo app()->db('connection');
```

How it should be? Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

Singletons should be avoided if possible, but I have found that when programming PHP, a `Config` is the one exception where a singleton always seems to make sense.

There is one rule though:

I strongly discourage using it in other objects. Not even with dependency injection or anything like that. (Not that DI really applies to singletons). Instead, what I do is on each PHP page, right at the top, (or in a bootstrap file for commonly used variables and classes that use them), write code which creates the necessary objects, and takes the data they need from the `Config` class. This means the objects don't need to know about how configuration values are obtained, or even what class obtains them, or how that class works.

This actually falls into the `Controller` pattern, even though you're not using any kind of MVC framework or controller objects. Each php page (entry point, e.g. the URL the user navigates to) acts as a controller. IMO it aids implementing MVC in a way that is native to PHP with minimal code.